# Three.js Texture in shaderMaterial

Tags: javascript, three.js

I could not load texture to my shader material, only what I see are just black dot. This is my shader.js

```
THREE.ShaderLib['cloud'] = {

    uniforms: {
        texture: { type: "t", value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("img/cloud.png") }
    },

    vertexShader: [
        "varying vec2 vUv;",
        "void main() {",
            "vUv = uv;",
            "gl_PointSize = 8.0;",
            "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);",
        "}",
    ].join("\n"),

    fragmentShader: [
            "varying vec2 vUv;",
            "uniform sampler2D texture;",
            "void main() {",
                "gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, vUv);",
            "}",
    ].join("\n")
};
```

and this is how I'm trying to load and use it:

```
var cloudShader = THREE.ShaderLib["cloud"];
var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(cloudShader.uniforms);

var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("img/cloud.png", undefined, function () {

   uniforms.texture.value = texture;
   texture.needsUpdate = true;

   var _material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
      fragmentShader: cloudShader.fragmentShader,
      vertexShader: cloudShader.vertexShader,
      uniforms: uniforms                   
   });                    
   _material.uniforms.texture.value.needsUpdate = true;
   var _geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
   _geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
   var _mesh = new THREE.Points(_geometry, _material);
   scene.add(_mesh);

 });
```

As You can see I'm trying to set update texture value two times, before and after material is created. It's really simpy example but I have no idea why it is not working in the way that I'm using it. There is no errors in debug console.

I'm using THREE.Points class, because I'm using it to generate clouds as a particle groups.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you sure you are able to access local file on your browser?

Comment: what local file ? You mean cloud.png ?, yes I'm sure :)

Comment: Why are you calling loadTexture twice?

Comment: just to test, I've already try to load in only one place, nothing change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after some time I have found a solution for this specific problem. I need to move my uniforms from shader.js directly to place where i'm creating shader material. This is enough to fix problem with my texture, but still I don't know why previous code doesn't work. Working shader material looks like this:

```
 var _material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
      fragmentShader: cloudShader.fragmentShader,
      vertexShader: cloudShader.vertexShader,
      uniforms: uniforms: {
        texture: { type: "t", value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("img/cloud.png") }
      },
 });
```

Comment: These days one should use [TextureLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/TextureLoader) instead